# larger flex child causing previous sibling's padding to be ignored

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have a flexbox but I'm having trouble understanding why the first child's padding gets ignored when the second child's content overflows.

here's an example when the second child's content aren't overflowing.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.title {
  background-color: green;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.body {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="title">

  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's an example when the child's content are overflowing

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.title {
  background-color: green;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.body {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="title">

  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can see in the second example that the title's height has greatly reduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're using flex css, which tries to accommodate all the children. If the title is supposed to not change in size no matter what, you need to set its flex-shrink to 0.

So try changing the css to:

```
.title {
  background-color: green;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```